# scrollToTop doesn't work in react (codesandbox)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In react, I am trying to make scrollToTop work.

Somehow, It doesn't work.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quiet-shape-5iov0?file=/src/App.js Here is the codesandbox. scroll down and there's should be button, called `click` which scrolls up, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Try this if you just need to scroll top.

```
  window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
```

function

```
const nice = () => {
    window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  };
```

Another way using **`scrollIntoView()`**

```
const nice = () => {
    document.querySelector("body").scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  };
```

For better understanding, checkout [window.scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Answer (score 0):

The scrollTo is a window function so just attach it there:)

```
window.scrollTo({
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scroll to top by using the window object like this :

```
  window.scrollTo(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use `window` object

```
    const nice = () => {
    const root = document.querySelector("body");
    console.log(root, " root");
    root.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth"
    });
  };
```